# Is there a way to determine if my code is run in an embedded Python?

Tags: python, cpython

So we're developing a C++ Python application that is both used in native Python and also in a embedded Python version that is wrapped in R using reticulate. Now we want to determine whether the currently running Python is in embedded mode or not.

Does anyone know what I could do here? I have not found any documentation about different env setups or internal hints that I could use to find this information within Python. We would have to determine on the Python side and not the C++ side...

I appreciate any hint I could get!

Edit about environments:
The main problem is that we use an embedded Python version with our R application and a native Python version with our main application. So our clients can access the same code snippet from basically any Python version that is included in the PY_LIMITED_API. So if I recall it correctly thats any version `3.2+`

Comment: maybe `sys.platform` or something in os.

Comment: sadly neither the `sys` nor `platform` modules give information that I can use to determine for sure that this Python is embedded or not. At least I have not found any info yet...

Comment: maybe `platform.processor()` ? Please give more information about your environments (embedded and native) this could help to search in the good direction

Comment: Or is it running always on same platform ? 
A patch could be to execute your python scripts with some parameter when calling from R. Your script would know the source because you tell him explicitly

Comment: What i get from the documentation is that `platform.processor()` only gives me information on what processor is runnig this code. That would not help me since both embedded and native can be run on basically any pc our clients manage to make it run. I'll update my question for a bit more information about the environments

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve here? If there is something that does not work in one of the environments, you should use the EAFP principle (try it, catch the exception if something fails and act accordingly).

Comment: The Python application is run both in native Python and through the wrapper in R. After installing the application we're writing a registry key according to the language used with the app(R or Python) to notify our software which API has already been installed. Now since R uses the entire Python program but is run in an embedded environment we have to differentiate in our Python code between native/embedded. Thus I'm asking here for ways to find out whether Python code is run in embedded or not. I hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't answered my question until now.

My workaround was a simple

```
try:
    import pip
except ImportError:
    PythonIsRunEmbedded = True
```

Since pip is not included with the embedded version of Python

Comment: did you or you did not answer your question?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes this is the answer to my question. I've just forgotten to post a proper answer back when I asked my question.

Comment: then better edit your answer and correct it to: "I haven't answered my question UNTIL NOW." Which is a bit redundant, so you can just remove the first sentence in order to avoid any further confusion.